# Filter array of objects in liquid

Tags: ruby, liquid

I'm new to Ruby. I want to filter array of objects in liquid. Based on [docs](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/) I created this code.

Example:

```
require 'liquid'

Liquid::Template.error_mode = :strict


context = {'fruits' => [{'name' => 'apple', 'good' => false}, {'name' => 'orange', 'good' => true}]}
template = '
{% assign good_fruits = fruits | where: "good" %}
{{ good_fruits }}'

puts Liquid::Template.parse(template).render(context)
```

Expected output:

```
{"name"=>"orange", "good"=>true}
```

Real output:

```
{"name"=>"apple", "good"=>false}{"name"=>"orange", "good"=>true}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i have copied the above code and ran...  it was working correctly on `ruby 3.1.2 (Linux)`..... And my output was same as expected output u have mentioned...

Comment: The problem was at my end. I used the old version of liquid. :(